# Creating or Instiatiating an ArrayList of Objects for Each User

Tags: java, arraylist

Alright so, I am building an online registration system for a university. It's a fairly basic system written in java so there's no database issue to worry about. My problem is this: I have a class of objects called Course. Each course has a list of attribute (id, time, instructor, etc.). Each user then, has an arraylist (or schedule if you will) of Course objects which they can add or remove. My question is how do I create an arraylist for each student/user? Would it be beneficial to have a separate arraylist of Courses like a catalog from which to choose from? Any advice on the subject would be of help. If you'd like to see an example of my code thus far let me know and I'll edit my post to include it.

```
public class Course {
private int courseId;
private String courseDes;
private String courseIns;
private int time;

public Course(int courseId, String courseDes, String courseIns, int time) {
    courseId = this.courseId;
    courseDes = this.courseDes;
    courseIns = this.courseIns;
    time = this.time;

}
```

Comment: Pretty much the most basic way would be to have a `Map<UserIdentifier, ArrayList<Course>>`, where `UserIdentifier` is some type you use to identify a specific user.

Comment: could you provide your code and will answer from that

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Map interface what exactly would that do?

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html): `An object that maps keys to values.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use maps; you've expressed the right relationship yourself: "Each user *has* an `ArrayList`". The way to express a has-a relationship is with instance fields:

```
public class Student {
    private final List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    //write methods that operate on courses, or make courses public
    ....
```

Representing courses as a Course object is simplest if you care about the properties of the courses in any way. If however you only need the know the course ID, or if you need to be storing a large amount of Students, you can save space by storing courses as integers or shorts and looking them up in a static table.

Comment: After thinking about the problem for a while I came to the same conclusion. However, shouldn't the arraylist in the student class be public? Or do we keep them private for encapsulation sake.

Comment: @QuailMan It could be public if you want Student to accept any combination of `Course`s; however in practice you likely want to control access to `courses` to ensure that students have sane schedules, eg. sorting courses chronologically, not taking the same class twice, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would have three separate classes Courses, Student and Enrollment.

```
public class Course {

    private int courseId;
    private String courseDes;
    private String courseIns;
    private int time;


    public Course(int courseId, String courseDes, String courseIns, int time) {
        courseId = this.courseId;
        courseDes = this.courseDes;
        courseIns = this.courseIns;
        time = this.time;
    }
}
```

Student

```
public class Student {

    private final int studentID;
    private final String name;
    private Set<Course> studentCourses;

    public Student(int studentId, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.studentID = studentId;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getStudentId(){
        return this.studentID;
    }

    void addCourse(Course course) {
        if(!studentCourses.contains(course)){
            studentCourses.add(course);
        }
        else{
            studentCourses.remove(course);
            studentCourses.add(course);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 23 * hash + this.studentID;
        hash = 23 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (this.studentID != other.studentID) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }     
}
```

Enrollment

```
class Enrollment{
    //This Map will group student with the same name
    private Map<String, List<Student>> enrollment;

    public Enrollment(Student student){
       if(enrollment.containsKey(student.getName())){               
           enrollment.get(student.getName()).add(student); 
       }else
       {
           List<Student> newStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
           newStudent.add(student);
           enrollment.put(student.getName(), newStudent);
       }
    }

    public void addCourse(Student student, Course course){

        try{
           List<Student> studentSameName = enrollment.get(student.name);
           for(Student studentEntry : studentSameName){
               if(studentEntry.getStudentId() == student.getStudentId()){
                   studentEntry.addCourse(course);
               }
           }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            //student does not exist
            //TODO Add Logic
        }
    }

    public void removeStudent(Student student){
        //TODO  Add Logic
    }        
}
```